# How can I pull the last changes from remote branch in Github?

Tags: git, github

I have common github repo with others. Someone implemented a code in his branch named `refactor/changes` and pushed it into our common repo without opening pull request.

I access it through this code shown below

```
git branches -a
git checkout -b refactor/changes remotes/origin/refactor/changes
```

Someone also added some codes in the repo and pushed it again.

How can I get the last changes from remotes/origin/refactor/changes to my local branch named refactor/changes ?

Comment: Why not `git pull`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Actually, How can I get it?

Comment: Have you tried typing `git pull` and pressing Enter?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Is `git pull` enough for that as I don't know?

Comment: Why don't you just try it? It could be enough.

Comment: If you don't know `git pull`, maybe reading a small introduction tutorial about git is good idea...

Comment: Don’t listen to these people. Use `git fetch`. ;)

Comment: @Philippe I know `git pull` but I want to make a sure this command is used for that.

Comment: @S.N You should try it and see. Fortunately almost anything you do with git is reversable, so there's very little risk in testing most commands.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the answer shown below.

`git fetch`

Comment: I recommend that you read more about both `git fetch` and `git pull`. They do two different things and are both useful depending on the result you want.